# Three.js - Flickering Texture

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, blender

I am trying to load a JSON file that I exported from blender.
There are two meshes and two materials in the file.
This is the code that I use to load the JSON.

```
var self = this;
var mushroomLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    mushroomLoader.load('/js/Mushroom.js', function(mushroomGeometry, mushroomMaterial) {
    var shrooms = new THREE.Object3D();
    var mushroomCount = 10;
    var radius = 30;
        for(var i = 0; i < mushroomCount; i++) {
        var m = new THREE.Object3D();
    m.add(new THREE.Mesh(mushroomGeometry, mushroomMaterial[0]));
    m.add(new THREE.Mesh(mushroomGeometry, mushroomMaterial[1]));
        m.position.x = radius * Math.cos(Math.PI * 2 * i / mushroomCount);
        m.position.z = radius * Math.sin(Math.PI * 2 * i / mushroomCount);
    shrooms.add(m);
    }
    self.scene.add(shrooms);
}, 'images/textures');
```

The mushroom is separated into two meshes, the top and the trunk. I am using MeshPhongMaterial. The texture that is flashing/disappearing is on the top. The weird thing is that some of them display correctly.

Comment: You appear to be adding two child meshes with identical geometry to each object, with the child meshes both in the same location. If so, that will cause z-fighting and flickering.

Answer (score 2):

You were right @WestLangley!
I changed my code from this

```
var m = new THREE.Object3D();
m.add(new THREE.Mesh(mushroomGeometry, mushroomMaterial[0]));
m.add(new THREE.Mesh(mushroomGeometry, mushroomMaterial[1]));
```

to

```
var m = new THREE.Mesh(mushroomGeometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(mushroomMaterial));
```

and I am not having anymore issues. It seems so simple in retrospect. I thought it was weird that THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject uses the same geometry for both meshes.